# Getting a “Google hasn’t verified this app” warning when creating a trigger - ok to ignore it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Getting a “Google hasn’t verified this app” warning when creating a trigger to run an app script on form submit (full warning text included below). It says until the developer verifies this app with Google, you shouldn’t use it.

This is purely an internal script and internal app being used in only our very small company. Does it still need to be “verified” by Google? It gives pretty dire warnings about what the app will be allowed to do, even though it is a simple app that doesn’t perform all those privileged things.

Overview of the app … a Google Form that stores responses in a Google Sheet. An app script (residing in the sheet) basically makes a copy of a Google Docs template file, and populates the copy with data from the sheet. We have a trigger to run the script on form submit. The warning is presented when the trigger is created, even when the same person is the owner of all parts – the app script “project”, trigger, form, sheet, docs, and shared folder on Google drive.

The warning just seems to pop-up once. In this scenario is it fine to just ignore it?

Full warning text below …

Google hasn’t verified this app.

The app is requesting access to sensitive info in your Google account. Until the developer (script owner’s email) verifies this app with Google, you shouldn’t use it.

Continue only if you understand the risks and trust the developer (script owner’s email).

Link: Go to (app_script_name) (unsafe)

… after clicking the link you get …

(app_script_name) wants to access your Google account

This will allow (app_script_name) to:

•   See, edit, create and delete all of your Google Drive files

•   See, create, and edit all Google Docs documents that you have access to

•   See, edit, create and delete your spreadsheets in Google Drive

•   View and manage your forms in Google Drive

Make sure you can trust (app_script_name)

You may be sharing sensitive info with this site or app. Learn about how (app_script_name) will handle your data by reviewing its terms of service and privacy policies. You can always see or remove access in your Google account.

(Buttons for Cancel or Allow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrote the script yourself, or trust its developer, there is no reason to not authorize the app.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I was missing something, i.e. if it had to be verified even if internal. But it meets the criteria so all is well to just authorize it internally.
Internal apps: if your app is an internal web app for users in the same G Suite domain and the app is associated with a Cloud Organization that all of your users belong to, you don't need to go through verification. For more information, see public and internal applications.

Answer (score 3):

### Your consent screen is being shown, but your app has not been reviewed

If your users are seeing the "unverified app" screen , it is because you haven't submitted your [app for verification](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914) or your OAuth request includes additional scopes that haven't been approved.

This warning shows up when:

- Your app uses sensitive or restricted scopes and you haven't configured them in your OAuth consent screen configuration page and requested verification.
- Your app uses sensitive or restricted scopes that you haven't selected on the OAuth consent screen configuration page.
- You selected sensitive or restricted scopes on the OAuth consent screen configuration page and requested verification, but the verification is not yet complete.

### References

- [Unverified apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865)
- [Verification Status](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615#verification-status)