# Access blocked: Project has not completed the google verification process

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am creating mobile app with google sign in feature where firebase authentication as a back end. When I am trying I am getting below error "Access blocked: Project-XXXXXXXXX7 has not completed the google verification process".

Front end : React native
Backend: Firebase, google authentication
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TlVC.png)

Creating Mobile app using React Native and Firebase as a backend.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this applies directly to your situation, but if you're still in the testing phase, you might want to try adding yourself to the list of "test" users in the OAuth consent screen (see image).  Just enter your google email address.
This worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may be following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25046173/3552975), but it seems that before you get a workable client ID [you should have your app reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67365837/3552975).